# Android AlarmManager BroadcastReceiver not working when user exits the application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm having some problems with a BroadcastReceiver that is supposed to react on an AlarmManager notification. I've read several threads on this subject but coulnd't find anything that would help. I must be missing something.

I set up the alarm the following way:

```
// Receiver intent
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, CalendarAlarmReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra(CalendarAlarmReceiver.SHOW, show);
// Sender
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, hashRequestCode(show), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mPendingAlarmRequests.put(show.getChannel() + show.getName() + show.getStart().toGMTString(), sender);
// Get AlarmManager
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, show.getStart().getTime(), sender);
```

I created an CalendarAlarmReceiver class that extends BroadcastReceiver. In the onReceive() method I start a status bar notification that works fine if the application is running. However, if I exit the application by clicking the back button until it closes, the notifications no longer appear.

I'm not sure if the receiver is called at all and it's just the notification that doesn't work or if the receiver is not called.

It is registered in the manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".calendar.CalendarAlarmReceiver" >
</receiver>
```

I read that this may not be the receiver's falut but rather the alarm may be cancelled when the application stops. If that is the case, is the solution to simply set the alarm in a service that is working all the time in the background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alarms are managed by the OS and are generally not cleared when your application 'exits'. Put some logging in your receiver and watch to logcat output to find out if it is called. If it is, debug your notification code.

Comment: Obviously, the notifications started popping up today even though I haven't introduced any changes. That's how I understood the AlarmManager - once I set it and the receiver is registered there's nothing more I need to do.

Comment: The debugging helped a lot I was thinking that broadcast stopped working after switching from implicit to explicit intent but ended a being a bug in my broadcast receiver logic when app was closed.

Answer (score 0):

The receivers should have intent filters for the broadcast they are listening to. As Nikolay mentioned in the comment below that this is not necessary if you are sending explicit intent. So keep that in mind.

```
<receiver android:name=".calendar.CalendarAlarmReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="REFRESH_THIS"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Similary, you intent code should set an action called "REFRESH_THIS" while sending it.

Have a look at [this](http://www.dotkam.com/2011/01/10/android-prefer-alarms-and-intent-receivers-to-services/) example. It explains the whole process with nice explanation.

Comment: You certainly don't need to add an intent filter with an action if you are using explicit intents, as the OP is.